# Failed to auto register types in Spring Boot (JPA/Joda/Jadira)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've researched and I can't see any answer for this one, although there are a lot of similar answers.

I have a Spring Boot application (`1.3.3.RELEASE`) that uses Spring Data JPA and Joda Time; I'm also using YAML for configuration purposes.

The issue is: I can't make it to auto register user types using Jadira.

This the relevant piece of my `application.yml` file:

```
  jackson:
    joda-date-time-format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
    serialization:
      write_dates_as_timestamps: false
  jpa:
    properties:
      #jadira_usertype_autoRegisterUserTypes: true
      jadira:
        usertype:
          autoRegisterUserTypes: true
```

...and this is one of the JPA entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POSTULATIONS")
public final class PostulationEntity implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 608398264869292985L;
  @Id
  @JsonProperty("id_postulation")
  @Column(name = "ID_POSTULATION") // columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)"
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  private String id;
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty("issued_at")
  @Column(name = "ISSUED_AT", nullable = false)
  //@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
  private DateTime issuedAt;
  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private PersonEntity person;
```

I want to be able to use `DateTime` types without specifying the `@Type`.

I've tried several approaches, but it's not working so far if I don't put the `@Type` annotation on every `DateTime` field.

Finally, this is the relevant piece for my Gradle configuration:

```
  dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    //compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:5.0.0.GA' // TODO: ?
    compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1' // TODO
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda' // TODO
  }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're using spring-boot so it looks like your project is pretty new.  If you havn't already considered changing from joda-time to using java8 datetimes I would suggest looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your yaml is wrong according to this post:
http://blog.jadira.co.uk/blog/2012/1/19/release-jadira-usertype-300cr1-with-support-for-joda-money-0.html

Try

```
jpa:
    properties:
      jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes: true
```

Comment: Thanks, but the YAML configuration is OK; notice the one-line setting is commented out. The "break-down" one is working.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours, I figured it out by *error-based testing*. Everything was almost fine, except the dependencies. The thrown exceptions on the console were almost useless, although by changing the configuration settings (and dependencies) they were different, so that's what gave me the idea to try with different dependencies since the data was imported successfully at some points.

Anyway, the `application.yml` file stays as it is (I'm deleting the commented-out line just to avoid confusions):

```
jackson:
  joda-date-time-format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
  serialization:
    write_dates_as_timestamps: false
jpa:
  properties:
    jadira:
      usertype:
        autoRegisterUserTypes: true
```

All JPA entities can now be used without the `@Type` annotation ― at least for the types I'm using.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POSTULATIONS")
public final class PostulationEntity implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 608398264869292985L;
  ...
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty("issued_at")
  @Column(name = "ISSUED_AT", nullable = false)
  private DateTime issuedAt;
```

...but *dependencies* was the key here and the factor that was causing my issue. First, I had to get rid of `org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime`, then put back/activate the `org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core` BUT version `4.0.0.GA` ― because version `5.0.0.GA` doesn't works with the default dependencies that comes with Spring Boot `1.3.3.RELEASE`. This is the final snippet:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
  compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:4.0.0.GA'
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda'
}
```

**NOTE:** The reason I'm not using versions on some other dependencies is because  I'm using the Spring dependencies management plug-in:

```
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
  compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:4.0.0.GA' // TODO
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda' // TODO
}
```